Raspberry Pi SSH Tunnel Service Error: Code "255/EXCEPTION"
I am new here.
I've recently implemented an SSH Tunnel Service on my Raspberry Pi. Here's the configuration of the service:
[Unit]
Description=SSH Tunnel with target server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -NT -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 127.0.0.1:10***:localhost:22 ubuntu@**.***.***.***
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
ReadWritePaths=/dev/null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I discovered the ReadWritePaths value online, intended to divert all errors to a null directory, preventing log overload. Nonetheless, the following error messages persistently fill the log:
May  6 12:32:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started SSH Tunnel with target server.
May  6 12:32:13 raspberrypi ssh[20599]: Error: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 10000
May  6 12:32:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: tunnel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
May  6 12:32:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: tunnel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  6 12:32:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: tunnel.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1185.
May  6 12:32:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped SSH Tunnel with target server.
May  6 12:32:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started SSH Tunnel with target server.

If anyone has a solution to this issue, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
